# Как сократить код при условии многие ко многим?

Tags: laravel

Может я конечно неправильно читал документацию, но связь многие ко многим работает при помощи `find()`, Но если мне нужно вывеси все значение у которого `id_user` равно авторизованному пользователю. То тут у меня проблема вышла. Возможно ли мне сократить код?

```
$directions = Direction::where('id_user', Auth::user()->id)->with('executes');
        $execute = [];
        foreach ($directions->get() as $value){
            foreach (Direction::find($value->id)->executes()->get() as $item){
                $execute[] = $item->name;
            }
        }
        dd($execute);
```

Пробовал такое значение `$roles = Direction::find(1)->executes();` Только минус мне нужны все значение которые попадает под условие `id_user = Auth::user()->id` в моделе Direction.
На счет `hasManyThrough` я так и не понял, подходит мне или нет
таблица у меня следующая
**Direction**

```
id
name
id_user
```

**Execute**

```
id
name
id_user
```

**Execute_direction**

```
direction_id
execute_id
```

Comment: А почему `id_user` не храните в таблице `Execute_direction` ?

Comment: А зачем нужно это? это же промежуточная таблица

Comment: Просто я не вижу смысла его туда добавлять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$executors = Executor::whereHas('directions', function($query) {
    $query->where('id_user', auth()->user()->id);
})
```

Comment: `auth()->user()->id`